# Missing condition in if statement error in go lang

Tags: go

I have this if statement that is not evaluating correctly:

```
// Take advantage of Boolean short-circuit evaluation
if h != 2 && h != 3 && h != 5 && h != 6 && h != 7 && h != 8
{
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
return 0
```

This is the error message -

```
missing condition in if statement
```

I have already tried putting the conditions in brackets etc.

Comment: I'm also learning Go currently. I have found that using Gofmt really cuts down, or eliminates entirely, this type of error. Good luck...https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/

Comment: yeah, I should start doing that, right now I run the programs directly in sublime..

Comment: I've been using LiteIDE, which can also run your Go code directly, but it will apply Gofmt before compiling, which is nice. Anyhow, good luck with it.

Comment: @Varun Install https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime is a sublime extension for go that (among other wonderful things) calls gofmt automatically before saving your file so each time you save it gets formatted automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to put the `{` at the end of the `if`:

```
if h != 2 && h != 3 && h != 5 && h != 6 && h != 7 && h != 8 {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
return 0
```

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/se_VHr2vC2).
See also "[Why does Golang enforce curly bracket to not be on the next line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17153873/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

You must have to put Curly Braches right after the if condition like this:

**Right example**

```
if(condition){
<code comes here>
}
```

**Wrong example**

```
if(condition)
{
<code comes here>
}
```